# breaking looping using(break;) and long code?

Tags: c#

If I'll use long code upon clicking a button, like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    my code segment 1
    my code segment 2
    my code segment 3
    etc
}
```

How to break if some condition would happen at any different stage within this long code. I know to break in looping; but how to break in this case?!

Comment: `return;` works just fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can exit early from a method using `return`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    my code segment 1
    if(condition)
    {
        return;
    }
    my code segment 2
    my code segment 3
    etc
}
```

Comment: +1, maybe I'm old school, but I always prefer {} around one-line if blocks.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a method.  You can `return` anytime you need to and end the method.

E.g.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    my code segment 1
    my code segment 2

    if (ConditionMet)
        return;

    my code segment 3
    etc
}
```